# How do I use a class inside of anther class?

Tags: php

I have a class that has some functions about accounts management, and I also got a class that validates email addresses, usernames and more.

How do I use the validation class inside the accounts class? How do I include it easliy?

Comment: you can `extend` the class or make it as an inner class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one class is specifically designed for validation purposes and another class is designed to contain instance-specific information, then there are three different approaches you can take.

**1) Statically reference the validator (*recommended*):**

```
<?php
class Validation {
  public static function validateEmail($email) {
    return filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
  }
}

class AccountManagement {
  public $email;
  public function __construct($email) {
    $this->email = $email;

    // Validate the e-mail. If not valid, an exception is thrown.
    if(!Validation::validateEmail($this->email)) {
      throw new InvalidArgumentException('$email argument supplied must contain a valid e-mail address');
    }
  }
}
```

**2) Extend your instance class to inherit from your validation class**

```
<?php
class Validation {
  public function validateEmail($email) {
    return filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
  }
}

class AccountManagement extends Validation {
  public $email;
  public function __construct($email) {
    $this->email = $email;

    // Validate the e-mail. If not valid, an exception is thrown.
    if(!$this->validateEmail($this->email)) {
      throw new InvalidArgumentException('$email argument supplied must contain a valid e-mail address');
    }
  }
}
```

**3) Instantiate your validation class from within your instance class (NOT RECOMMENDED):**

```
<?php
class Validation {
  public function validateEmail($email) {
    return filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
  }
}

class AccountManagement extends Validation {
  public $email;
  public function __construct($email) {
    $this->email = $email;

    $validator = new Validation;

    // Validate the e-mail. If not valid, an exception is thrown.
    if(!$validator->validateEmail($this->email)) {
      throw new InvalidArgumentException('$email argument supplied must contain a valid e-mail address');
    }
  }
}
```

**Testing your implementation**

Once you've chosen the method which best fits your needs (regardless of which one you choose), you can test it with the following code:

```
// Valid, should not throw an exception and should print success.
try {
  $account = New AccountManagement('me@myself.com');
  print "AccountManagement object successfully instantiated.<br />\r\n";
} catch(Exception $e) {
  print 'Error: Encountered ' . $e;
}

// Invalid, should throw an InvalidArgumentException exception
try {
  $account = New AccountManagement('myself.com');
  print "AccountManagement object successfully instantiated.<br />\r\n";
} catch(Exception $e) {
  print 'Error: Encountered ' . $e;
}
```

**Bonus Example:**

Sometimes, you may want to specifically catch Validation errors, and let something take care of any other exceptions which may be encountered. In this case, we can create a special exception just for our validator, and allow the validator to be the one to throw the exception:

```
<?php
class ValidationException extends Exception {
  // Will use default Exception behavior.
}

class Validation {
  public static function validateEmail($email) {
    if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      throw new ValidationException('E-mail address supplied is not valid');
    }
  }
}

class AccountManagement {
  public $email;
  public function __construct($email) {
    $this->email = $email;

    // Validate the e-mail.
    Validation::validateEmail($this->email);
  }
}

// Valid, should not throw an exception and should print success.
try {
  $account = New AccountManagement('me@myself.com');
  print "AccountManagement object successfully instantiated.<br />\r\n";
} catch(Exception $e) {
  print 'Error: Encountered ' . $e;
}

// Invalid, should throw an ValidationException exception
try {
  $account = New AccountManagement('myself.com');
  print "AccountManagement object successfully instantiated.<br />\r\n";
} catch(ValidationException $e) {
  print 'Error: Encountered ' . $e;
}
```

Comment: Didn't know that before, exactly what I needed. Thank you very much :)

Comment: I don't think use "print" is a reusable pattern for an HTML validator...

Comment: it's for a proof of concept, not for production.

Comment: Some significant changes have been made to the examples for the prude at heart (@X-Blaster): Replaced print statements with Exceptions for real-to-life scenarios. Added additional examples showcasing a few different implementations to fit the need of specific desires or behaviors. Added an example utilizing a custom exception for catching Validation-specific exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

You could instantiate the validation class and pass it into the accounts class as a paramater and set it as a property within the accounts class in the accounts constructor method?

Comment: Is it the easiest way doing that? That's the way I use right now.

Comment: Depends if the validation really needs to be an object. You can do as Joshua has suggested and use static methods within a class which doesn't require to be instantiated but you'll still need to include the validation file before calling a validation method. If you do go down that route you might want to look into spl_autoload_register and lazy-loading.

Answer (score -1):

You can maybe create a third class "AccountsManagementValidator" with methods

```
validate(AccountManagement): void
hasErrors(): boolean
getErrors(): List<Error>
```

There's a lot of different implementation but this I described is PlayFramework validator implementation.

Of course your "validator" class reuse your common method to validate email, users, etc...